# using php date format in mysql date_format

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to format a date in mysql SELECT where the Format is based on php Date function.

I have a mysql date column and i would like to run a query that will return the date in a php date format (d/m/y)?

thanks

Comment: Obviously this question has been asked many times, but in any case have a look to [MYSQL Date documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `DATE_FORMAT` function like this:

`DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: In PHP you would use date('d/m'/y').  If you use the same format in the DATE_FORMAT(Date, 'd/m/y') that would not work.  I think i asked the wrong question.  I should have asked how to take a 'd/m/y' to '%d/%m/%y'

Comment: i was able to get the format be doing few str_replace('d', '%d', $php_date_format)